# Trace Network and use results for another new trace

Tags: arcpy, geometric-network

Is it possible in arcpy to make different geometric traces?

Like when in trace A, a featurclass 1 is passed by the trace, a second trace B should begin at featureclass 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect so, by using the [Trace Geometric Network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/trace-geometric-network.htm) tool more than once within a script.

That tool:

> Solves the specified network analysis problem based on the flags,
>   barriers, and specified weight properties.

I recommend trying it, and if you get stuck, then post a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried, and where you are stuck, as a new question.